# resultset.getTimestamp and ThreadLocal warning Java

Tags: java, timestamp, resultset, thread-local

I have started getting lots of warnings whenever I restart my server lately.
The warning looks like this:

the web application [/xxx] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Support$1] (value [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Support$1@29173d71]) and a value of type [java.util.GregorianCalendar]
...
but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped.

I finally found the line in the code that creates it:

cp.setCreationDate(rset.getTimestamp("CreationDate"));

rset is of type java.sql.ResultSet

Is there something wrong with how I get the date from database or is there a way to remove the calendar?
We have always done it like this and I don't know why these errors has started, but they really spam the logs now.

I found this thread:
[Java ResultSet.getTimestamp using Calendar & Thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949289/java-resultset-gettimestamp-using-calendar-thread-safety)

but I still get the errors.

Comment: What is the type of cp?  Check the API for the setCreationDate method and see if there is a way to clear the information that the method stores.  You would then need to call this other method when the server shuts down.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
However cp is just some class.
If i change the line to:
Timestamp i = rset.getTimestamp("CreationDate"); 
The error is still there

Answer (score 1):

Call `rset.close()` once you have finished with the ResultSet object itself, which will release the resources which the ResultSet is holding onto.

Comment: I do close it I believe.

Posted a new post above this.

Comment: From the code you posted as an answer, if rset.getTimestamp() throws an SQLException, then rset.close() will not be called.  Try putting all the close() calls in the finally block.

Comment: Hey you are right, but that is not the problem.
There is no errors caught and the application works fine.
Its just these warnings that has appeared out of nowhere.
I now think it has to have to do with the environment somehow and not the code itself.
Something with java-version or imported jars or something that messes something up.
I realize this is pretty impossible for anyone to help out with given the info I have so I will leave this thread now. If I ever get eny wiser about this I will add any solutions to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I closed the resultset.
This is the code now (simplified to just show my problem):

```
public CompanyPerson getCompanyPerson(int personId) throws SQLException {           
    CompanyPerson person = new CompanyPerson(); 
    Connection con = null;  
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;

    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
    sql.append(" select CreationDate from  CMCompanyPeople person ");   
    sql.append(" where  person.PersonId=?");        

    try { 
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        pstmt.setInt(1,personId);

        rset = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if (rset.next()) { 
            Timestamp t = rset.getTimestamp("CreationDate");
        }

        rset.close(); 
        pstmt.close();
        con.close();          

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e; 
    } finally {
        closeConnection(con);

    }

    return person;
}
```

When i run the code the server restarted and I got the above error.

After removing the following code i did not get any error

Timestamp t = rset.getTimestamp("CreationDate");

What is going on here?